# vue router fail to redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

routes:

```
import vQuestion from './components/visitor/vQuestion';

import login from './components/auth/login';
import register from './components/auth/register';
import forgot from './components/auth/forgot';

import Home from './components/Home';
import Question from './components/Question/Question';
import Answer from './components/Answer/Answer';

export const routes = [
{ path: '/', name: 'vQuestion', component: vQuestion },
{ path: '/register', name: 'register', component: register },
{ path: '/login', name: 'login', component: login },
{ path: '/forgot', name: 'forgot',  component: forgot },
{ path: '/answer/:id', name: 'answer', component: Answer},

{ path: '/home', name: 'home', component: Home, meta: {requiresAuth: true}},
{ path: '/question', name:'question', component: Question, meta: {requiresAuth: true} },

];
```

i would like to set to answer is see any on logged or not

```
 <ul v-for="question in questions" v-bind:key="question.main" id="my-table">
     <router-link class="" :to="{name:'answer', params: {id: question.main}}">
           <p>{{question.title}}</p>
     </router-link>
 </ul>
```

but without login user can open this path,after login when user click this link that time path was not redirect

in main.js file

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes
});

router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('/');
    else if(!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('/home');
    else next();
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your router.js file used in your application?

Comment: first i have write routes is router.js file contain